# android.view.InflateException : error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am trying to add a fragment to an activity through XML. But app crashes and logcat shows this error.

**FinalActivity.java**

```
public class FinalActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_frm);
         }
}
```

**activity_final_frm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bar_"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slide_menu_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/slide_menu_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shop_button"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/shop_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_a_button"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/shop_button"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >
    <include layout="@layout/header_nav_layout" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <fragment
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.randomsell.FeautredProdFrag"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/footer_nav_layout" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**FeautredProdFrag.java**

```
public class FeautredProdFrag extends Fragment 
{
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feautred_prod, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_feautred_prod.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.randomsell.FeautredProdFrag">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/no_imgs_available"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.randomsell/com.randomsell.FinalActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2463)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.randomsell.FinalActivity.onCreate(FinalActivity.java:44)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.randomsell.FinalActivity@411feb98 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.randomsell.FeautredProdFrag.onAttach(FeautredProdFrag.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1155)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1030)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1237)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1339)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2295)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:342) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.randomsell.FinalActivity.onCreate(FinalActivity.java:44) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5165) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1103) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850) 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried following things already but that didn't work.

1. importing android.support.v4.app.Fragment
2. importing android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
3. changing android:name to class

Comment: @ArthurKorchagin , Logcat shows error on exact same line where fragment element starts in respective xml

Comment: The logcat also includes the nested "caused by" exception that is relevant.

Comment: @laalto , caused by says the same "Error inflating class fragment"

Comment: Post the logcat anyway with all the nested exceptions

Answer (score 0):

To me, instead of `android:name`, I use `class` as below:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/testFragment"
    class="com.my.fragment.TestFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ></fragment>
```

**Edit**:

After reading your logcat, look at the error line `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.randomsell.FinalActivity@411feb98 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.randomsell.FeautredProdFrag.onAttach(FeautredProdFrag.java:83)`. Error comes from here, not what you are trying to resolve. you should check your casting.

Answer (score 0):

From your logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.randomsell.FinalActivity@411feb98 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
  at com.randomsell.FeautredProdFrag.onAttach(FeautredProdFrag.java:83)
```

The problem is in your `FeautredProdFrag` `onAttach()` on line 83. Some object of yours apparently does not implement an interface that is required.

Answer (score 0):

The activity needed to implement **OnFragmentInteractionListener** so it becomes

```
public class FinalActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener
{
   protected void onCreate(Bundle bundleSavedInstance)
   {
      //code here 
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Uppercase Fragment in your layout xml file:

```
<Fragment> </Fragment>
```

Comment: Jorn, it doesn't work this way. Most layout elems such as <Button> refer to actual view classes so they are capatalized The exception to this are <fragment> and <include>.

Answer (score -1):

add

```
     @Override
```

before

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

If it doesn't work, post your Logcat